# How to declare namespace in response xml

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, dataweave

I'm doing POC in Data Weaver. I'm not sure how to declare namespace `ns0:` in throughout the output xml. Referred link:  https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/dataweave (I have seen examples on handling input xml with namespace 1.4.3, but I'm looking for output xml).

Input Xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Records>
      <storenumber>12</storenumber>
      <calculated>false</calculated>
      <subTotal>12</subTotal>
   <Records>
```

Expected Output xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' eencoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <ns0:orders 
       xmlns="ns2=urn:test.com:common:v1">
  <ns0:order>
    <ns0:StoreID>12</ns0:StoreID>
    <ns0:Total>false</ns0:Total>
   </ns0:order>
  </ns0:orders>
```

DataWeaver Transformation

```
%dw 1.0
 %output application/xml
 %var baseurl="ns2=urn:test.com:common:v1"
 ---
 orders @(xmlns:baseurl): {
 order: {
  StoreID: payload.Records.storenumber,
  Total: payload.Records.calculated
  }
}
```

I believe `@(xmlns:baseurl)` in the transformation is correct. Is there any other way to define it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Namespaces are declared with the directive `%namespace <prefix> <uri>`
You can specify the namespace of an element with `<prefix>#<element>`

DataWeave Transformation

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%namespace ns0 urn:test.com:common:v1
---
ns0#orders: {
  ns0#order: {
    ns0#StoreID: payload.Records.storenumber,
    ns0#Total: payload.Records.calculated
  }
}
```

Output

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns0:orders xmlns:ns0="urn:test.com:common:v1">
  <ns0:order>
    <ns0:StoreID>12</ns0:StoreID>
    <ns0:Total>false</ns0:Total>
  </ns0:order>
</ns0:orders>
```